# Handling Authentication in Symfony2 Unit-Tests

Tags: authentication, symfony

I want to write functional tests for Controllers that are secured via the Symfony2 authentication mechanisms. I read a lot of tutorials describing it but unfortunately all of them doesn't work for me with current Symfony2 version (tested 2.0.4 to 2.0.7)

What I have done so far:

**Adding security settings in config_test.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        main:
            users:
                admin:  { password: adminsmurf, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                inventory: { password: inventorysmurf, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_INVENTORY' ] }
                andon: { password: andonsmurf, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ANDON' ] }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    /.*
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Area"
                provider: main
            logout:     true
            security:   true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous: true
```

**Unit-Test**

```
class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testCorrectAuthentificationCredentials()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/inventory/index', array(), array(), 
                                    array(
                                          'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
                                          'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'adminsmurf'
                                        ));

        $response = $client->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

This test fails (Expected 200, get 302). Can anybody help what I'm doing wrong?

**Update 16/12**

I got a step further. As I'm using a form login in my regular security file. Symfony just added the http_basic login to the firewall. This was the reason for the redirect (302). I just added a

```
form_login: false
```

to the test security settings. Now there is no redirect but I get an 401 status code as a result.

Comment: 302 is a redirection. Could you check where are you redirected to?

Comment: @kuba it is a redirect to the login form (Form login is the regular way for authentication in my app).

Comment: I solved the problem with the redirect, but now I have a status code 401

Answer (score 3):

I'm showing that the HTTP basic auth should go as the 4th argument to request, not the 5th. Source is the docs - if they don't work, we need to update them. But let me know:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html

Also, once you have this working correctly, you can turn form auth back on, as Symfony won't have any reason to use the form's entry point (<-- fancy word :)) to redirect you.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the test environment uses a separate database, but I had forgotten to populate it with users. m)

I know, this is probably not really a solution to your problem, but let's see how many upvotes this gets if everyone with the same problem upvotes. If nobody does, well, I'm the only one who's that stupid.

By the way, you could try an in-memory provider to see whether your authentication fails because of database issues or the like. That's how I found out what my problem was.