# Authentication into functional tests not perfectly working

Tags: php, symfony, testing, session-cookies

Since all my project resources are protected so user needs to get authenticated. In my tests I authenticate once in the setUp function. This works only for the first `$client->request`, if I try another `$client->request` after the first request, `$client->getResponse()->getContent()` says that I'm not authenticated!!

If I call the auth function (definition's below) to get authenticated, the second request works.

So to sum up, currently I'm compelled to authenticate for every `$client->request(..`.

Here is my function I'm using for authentication ([How to log in User in Session within a Functional Test in Symfony 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015385/how-to-log-in-user-in-session-within-a-functional-test-in-symfony-2-3))

```
public function auth($username, &$client)
{
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $firewall = 'front';

    $user = $this->doctrine->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());

    $client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie(session_name(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

Why do I need to authenticate for every request? Is it because somehow the session or the cookiejar generated by `public function auth` are not passed to the other requests  ?

Comment: If you're writing your tests properly, each test is independent from the others.  Ergo, you need to authenticate each and every time.  If you only want to authenticate once, set up a test fixture at the beginning of the tests, and write your tests to all use that same test fixture.

Comment: My bad, I meant into the same test I need to run many requests. So into say `public function testMytest1` for instance, I have to authenticate for every request?

Comment: Just found a better way here http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html. Works like a charm. I'd be very interested to understand the difference between the two types of authentication though

Comment: @smarber HTTP authentification uses a dialog displayed by the browser, not a `<form>` in a HTML page.