# How to Log User from Functional Testing with Symfony

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

I use `FOSUserBundle` for my User Authentication
I have a controller, let's call it `adminController` which is reserved for User granted `User::ADMIN_ROLE`
Everything works fine but I have an error when I try to write my functional Test

Inside my `AdminControllerTest` I have a method that try to test a page that need `User::ADMIN_ROLE`

My `testAdminAccess()`  method

```
public function testAdminAccess()
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    // the firewall context defaults to the firewall name
     = 'main';

    $user = $this->getUserByUsername('admin@yopmail.com');

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallContext, $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    $this->client->followRedirects();

    $crawler = $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        'http://localhost/admin'
    );

    dump($crawler);
}
```

I'm always redirected to my login page

How can I keep the session to access some page that's protected by a specific Role?

What I'm already tried:

- http://kristiankaa.dk/symfony-authentication-controller-testing
- [How to log in User in Session within a Functional Test in Symfony 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015385/how-to-log-in-user-in-session-within-a-functional-test-in-symfony-2-3/19058259#19058259)
- https://symfony-docs-zh-cn.readthedocs.io/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html
- [How to programmatically login/authenticate a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user)

I'm using Symfony version 3.4

Answer (score 0):

The best is to login the user normally submitting the username and password like a standard user would do, I use a function like this (adapt your paths):

```
/**
 * Log the test user for the connected tests.
 */
public function login(string $username = null, string $password = null): KernelBrowser
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    // Login page
    $client->request('GET', '/en/login/');
    $this->assertTrue($kernelBrowser->getResponse()->isOk());

    // Auth
    $token = $client->getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate');
    $client->request('POST', '/login_check', [
        '_csrf_token' => $token,
        '_username' => $username ?? 'test',
        '_password' => $password ?? 'test',
        '_remember_me' => 'on',
    ]);

    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
    $client->followRedirect();

    return $client;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with the form is that I have a Two Factor Authentication :(

Comment: Why isn't it written in the question?